# Accessing XML file from remote machine

Tags: c#, xml

I want to access xml file from remote machiene say "a.abc.int" I am using following code to do this

```
string reportPath = @"\\a.abc.int\c$\Program Files\abc\File.xml";
XmlDocument reportParameter = new XmlDocument();
reportParameter.Load(reportPath);
XmlElement reportParameterReader = reportParameter.DocumentElement;
```

but I get an exception at

```
reportParameter.Load(reportPath); 
retrun exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}
```

Comment: Is this a machine on your network (like a mapped drive), or a remote machine outside your network (like maybe a website)?

Comment: No machine is not on my network its on other domain..

Answer (score 0):

If the machines are part of the same domain, you can [impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w070t6ka.aspx) your code with a user of the Domain who have right. (Try Domain/Administrator) if it work problem is clearly sharing right problem.